# Wanted to disable history -c for all users except the one with sudo rights?

Tags: bash, history, bash-history

I am able to secure `.bash_history` and `.profile files` so that user cannot delete or edit those files and cannot change shell as well.

I needed this for bastion host for all production instances. I need to disable `history -c` and `history -r` or even if possible `history` command itself. At least, `history` command can only be run via `sudo`.

Comment: `history` is a command that *cannot* be run with `sudo`, since it's a shell builtin, and not an external executable at all. You should  look up auditing instead of this.

Comment: You could also look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94447/423684),  to get an idea how to store your history in a custom file and set the permissions so that only sudoers have read permission on that file.