# How to save terminal commands differently?

Tags: command-line, history

I am taking some online courses. I want to seperate all commands. That is, I want to save all commands that I execute during classes on a different memory file than my other system commands. This will make my work easy when I work on the system and when I work on classes.

Is it possible to save terminal commands on different files and then load previous commands from a specific file? If yes, how can this be done?

If you are not able to understand the problem properly, here`s an example.

Type 1:- During classes, I use commands for compiling and executing files, like **"gcc abcd.c -o abcd"** and **"abcd"**

Type 2:- But, while working on system, I use commands like **"sudo apt install ..."** or **"sudo apt purge ..."**
Now, when I want to use previous system commands after a class, I will be having lots of commands of type 1 and it will be annoying. So, I want to save type 1 and type 2 commands differently on different files and load a specific file whenever I require.

Details about the system:-
Shell - /bin/bash

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

**UPDATE**
According to @Marc Vanhoomissen, I was able to create another history file and named it **.classes** (Note:- .class is used for java files. so I can`t use it).
I open terminal, see that it is using **bash_history** as HISTFILE. Then I change to **.classes**, but the commands did not change. The command in the image is **NOT** specified in **.classes** file. On top of that, it does not show the commands of **.classes** file at all.
[image: The last command is not in the .classes file]

[image: .classes file]
None of these commands can be seen in the terminal even after loading **.classes** history file

Comment: You've provided no OS, release details or shell details. I type loads of commands for support purposes on my boxes so I don't have any of them reach my command history so it's not cluttered with packages queries for others on sites like this. I also have the date & time of the commands stored in the history, which I find useful (and maybe useful to you too..) but commands and how varies particularly on shell, but also OS & release (and if local, remote-user etc)

Comment: @Master_Nachi you need to clear current history (this does not clear to file just the memory) `history -c` then re-read the file `history -r`

Comment: Thanks @bac0n, it worked! but I need to clear and read history every time I open terminal. No problem, i`ll manage. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of commands you entered is stored in a specific file, specified normally in the `.bashrc` file of your user home directory.  This file is customizable and you can change the name of the file by setting:

```
HISTFILE=.class
```

or

```
HISTFILE=.pers
```

Instead, you can just specify

```
$ HISTFILE=.class
```

or

```
$ HISTFILE=.pers
```

at the command prompt.  This will create separate files.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the versatile `history` has a single file.
That file can changed on a per-session basis, but not per-command.

You did not specify how you would split your commands into "types" as you call them.
Lacking that info, you can probably use `grep`:

```
history | grep gcc > history_gcc.txt
```

will create file `history_gcc.txt` containing all commands with `gcc`.

**Related**:

1. [Can I create a separate bash history file for each terminal profile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94439/can-i-create-a-separate-bash-history-file-for-each-terminal-profile)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56446/shell-deal-with-multiple-command-history-files